# nested function memory usage in javascript

Tags: javascript, memory, closures

I sort of understand closures in javascript, but what I'm not sure about is how it treats nested functions. For example:

```
var a = function(o) {
    o.someFunction(function(x) {
        // do stuff
    });
}
```

I know a new closure is created everytime I call function `a`, but does that closure also include a new instance of the anonymous function passed to `someFunction`? Would it better if I did the ff instead:

```
var b = function(x) { /* do stuff */ }
var a = function(o) {
    o.someFunction(b);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your first example, every time that a is called, an anonymous function is defined and passed to `someFunction()`. This is more expensive than what you've got in the second example, which is the more efficient method, since the function (now called b) is only being defined once.

I asked a question similar to this a few months back: it might help you as well. [Does use of anonymous functions affect performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80802/does-use-of-anonymous-functions-affect-performance)

Comment: Thanks, the link to your question was very helpful.