# Will creating a function within a constructor function use more memory than referencing a prototype function?

Tags: javascript, browser, memory-management, function, closures

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript: Setting methods through prototype object or in constructor, difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/422476/javascript-setting-methods-through-prototype-object-or-in-constructor-differenc)

I guess this is a question about the browsers implementation of closures really.  I know about the numerous ways to emulate Class-like functionality within JavaScript including using various libraries.  This is more a question about resources.

Does creating a function in this manner **create a new copy of `public_function` function each time it is called**?  the underlying question is: Does doing it this way use more RAM than adding the function to `MyObject.prototype` ?

```
function MyObject(){
  this.public_function = function(){
    //... do something
  }
}
```

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/422476/javascript-setting-methods-through-prototype-object-or-in-constructor-differenc

Comment: Would someone please mark this as a dupe of one of the below linked questions, maybe this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/80802/does-use-of-anonymous-functions-affect-performance

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

If nothing else, this requires a slot on every object created by `new MyObject()` rather than a single slot on the prototype.

But of course, there *is* something else: the anonymous function creates a closure, capturing the scope in which it is defined. And again, that has to be stored *for every object* created by MyObject.

Whether this actually *matters* will depend on how many objects you create...

#### See also:

> - [nested function memory usage in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/637552/nested-function-memory-usage-in-javascript)
> - [JavaScript instance functions vs. prototype functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1441212/javascript-instance-functions-vs-prototype-functions)

Answer (score 0):

For a class that has mulitipul instances, an anonymous function defined in constructor will create a new copy of function for each instance.

another way without using prototype is that define a static function and assign it to the member. For example:

```
function A(){
    this.hello = Hello;
}

function Hello(){
    alert('hello');
}
```