# jQuery / Ajax - $.ajax() Passing Parameters to Callback - Good Pattern to Use?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, callback

JavaScript code I'm starting with:

```
function doSomething(url) {  
   $.ajax({
      type: "GET",  
      url: url,  
      dataType: "xml",  
      success: rssToTarget  
   });  
}
```

Pattern I would like to use:

```
//where elem is the target that should receive new items via DOM (appendChild)
function doSomething(url, elem) {
   $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: url,
      dataType: "xml",
      success: rssToTarget(elem)
   });
}
```

I don't think I can get the callback to work this way, right? What is the proper pattern? I don't want to use global variables necessarily to temporarily hold the `elem` or elem name.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602981/jquery-how-to-pass-additional-parameters-to-success-callback-for-ajax-call use invokedata

Comment: For future reference: You need to store the callback function (`rssToTarget`) within the `success` property of the object literal you are passing to `$.ajax()`, so jQuery can call that function once the AJAX request is completed. By adding `(elem)` to the end of the function name, you are mistakenly invoking `rssToTarget` and storing its return value within `success`. In JS, adding parentheses at the end of a function name will invoke it.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Like this...

```
function doSomething(url, elem) {
  $.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: url,
     dataType: "xml",
     success: function(xml) {
       rssToTarget(xml, elem);
     }
  });
}
```

Answer to your comment: [Does use of anonymous functions affect performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80802/does-use-of-anonymous-functions-affect-performance)

Comment: aha +1. Do you pay any performance price for creating anon functions everywhere?

Comment: And I guess it would really be.... success: function(xml) { rssToTarget(xml, elem); }

Comment: if you wrap your `$.ajax` call in a loop, this approach will create new function (`function(xml) { ... }`) for every loop, consuming more memory.

Answer (score 30):

The pattern you'd like to use could work if you create a [closure](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/closures.shtml) inside your rssToTarget function:

```
function rssToTarget(element) {
  return function (xmlData) {
    // work with element and the data returned from the server
  }
}

function doSomething(url, elem) {
    $.ajax({ type: "GET",
         url: url,
         dataType: "xml",
         success: rssToTarget(elem)
       });
}
```

When `rssToTarget(elem)` is executed, the element parameter is stored in the [closure](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/closures.shtml), and the callback function is returned, waiting to be executed.

Comment: -1 You cant set success to a function that returns a function.

Comment: I forgot to add " but requires a parameter"

Comment: of course you can return a function check the code running! http://jsbin.com/anepo/edit

Comment: The returned anonymous function has an input parameter... JavaScript functional capabilities allows you to do that and more with functions...

Comment: What about the normal success callback function parameter ? (data, textStatus, jqXHR) ?

Comment: I mean  , the success call back should get 3 params from the ajax response evemt. where are they in your answer? ( or maybe i didnt understand it  ...)

Comment: @RoyiNamir JavaScript functions are variadic, they can be called with more (or less!) parameters than their definitions call for. Rest assured that this example works as intended.

Comment: This answer more faithfully reproduces what the OP wanted to achieve than the accepted answer does.

Comment: @CMS Is this approach fundamentally the same as the accepted answer i.e. use closure for passing data to callback?

Comment: I like this approach, esp if I need to wrap `$.ajax` call in a loop, I don't have to create new function for every loop. Great approach!

Answer (score 0):

What about exploting [Ajax request settings context](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)?

```
function doSomething(url, elem) {
   $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: url,
      dataType: "xml",
      success: rssToTarget,
      elem: elem               // <- add as settings argument
   });
}

rssToTarget(ans) {
    elem = this.elem;          // <- get it back using "this"
}
```

By default callback context is a merge of `$.ajaxSettings` and settings passed to `$.ajax`. So if you add your fields in `$.ajax` settings they go into callback context. That is, you can retrieve them from context using `this`.