# What's the difference between calling a javascript function with arguments, and without

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was trying to get data back from an ajax call, and was using the code

```
jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/chatlog',
        success: exoticlangAjaxCompleted,
        data:'messageLog=' + privateMessageLogJson,
        dataType: 'json'
    });
```

The data was in a JSON array (key = "messageLog")

Why did it work to call

```
    success: exoticlangAjaxCompleted,
```

but not

```
    success: exoticlangAjaxCompleted(),
```

or

```
    success: exoticlangAjaxCompleted(messageLog) ??
```

JS function is:

```
function exoticlangAjaxCompleted(messageLog){
    console.log('exoticlangAjaxCompleted!');
    console.log('chat log is: ' + messageLog);
    console.log('chat log is: ' + dump(messageLog));
}
```

Comment: you are replacing an event handler. That has to be done with a function or something that returns a function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `success` argument expects a reference to  function that will be invoked when the AJAX request is complete.

With the following:

```
success: exoticlangAjaxCompleted,
```

You are passing a reference to a function as required.

Whereas in this instance:

```
success: exoticlangAjaxCompleted(),
```

You are invoking your `exoticlangAjaxCompleted` function and passing the result to the `success` argument. Unless your function returns a function, this will not work!

Comment: Yea. Also every JS function is by default associated with a variable in the same name. That means if you have `function abc(){}`, then you also have a var `abc`, which you can use to refer to the function. In your case, `exoticlangAjaxCompleted` refers to the original function.

Comment: Thanks to all - I'll do more research on passing by reference

Answer (score 2):

The reason the former syntaxes work is because `success` expects a function object (in order to call it with arguments, if it wanted to), where just calling a function doesn't return a function object. When you call a function with the `function()` form, it produces *an output* (even if that output is undefined) This is also why this form works:

```
...
success: function() {
    // Some callback code
}
...
```

So, how are they different? To show how, let's look at the WebKit console:

[image: Image showing the WebKit console, myFunc vs myFunc()]

As you can see, executing `myFunc` returns the **function itself**, whereas `myFunc()` returns **an object that would be useless to `select:`*

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that you can't pass arguments this way.

If you try doing this:

```
success: function(){exoticlangAjaxCompleted(messageLog);},
```

Then that might work.

Answer (score 0):

From the Jquery documentations, here is a section about the success callback:

> "A function to be called if the request succeeds. The function gets
>   passed three arguments: The data returned from the server, formatted
>   according to the dataType parameter; a string describing the status;
>   and the jqXHR (in jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHttpRequest) object."

[jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

So you have to make a trick, like here:  [Pattern of additional parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1194104/jquery-ajax-ajax-passing-parameters-to-callback-good-pattern-to-use)

```
success: function(..){
...
}
```