# pass data through a ajax request to a callback function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, request

Is it possible to pass data through a Ajax request to the Callback function without global variables?

for e.g. this request function should pass the passData through the callback function which should get also normal response data?!

```
function rquest(callback, passData){
    $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: someURL,
         success: callback(passData)
    });
};  

function myCallback(data, passData){
    var responseData = data;
    var SomeOtherData = passData
    //do Something
};

rquest(myCallback, "Hello World");
```

so "Hello World" should be in passData and data should be the normal response from server...if i do it in this way data is "Hello World" and passData is undefined.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Wrap the call to the provided callback in an anonymous function. Try this:

```
function rquest(callback, passData){
    $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: someURL,
         success: function(data) { 
             callback(data, passData)
         }
    });
};  

function myCallback(data, passData) {
    var responseData = data;
    var SomeOtherData = passData
    //do Something
};

rquest(myCallback, "Hello World");
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer in the below link - some more patterns are available to achieve this - 
Adding some of the content from the reference answer.

The pattern you'd like to use could work if you create a [closure](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/closures.shtml) inside your rssToTarget function:

```
function rssToTarget(element) {
  return function (xmlData) {
    // work with element and the data returned from the server
  }
}

function doSomething(url, elem) {
    $.ajax({ type: "GET",
         url: url,
         dataType: "xml",
         success: rssToTarget(elem)
       });
}
```

When `rssToTarget(elem)` is executed, the element parameter is stored in the [closure](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/closures.shtml), and the callback function is returned, waiting to be executed.

Reference link https://stackoverflow.com/a/1194187/3082706