# Can't access a global array inside $.getJSON function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, api

I am making a 'viewer' for Twitch TV, which shows if TV channels are online,offline or don't exist. I am using the API for Twitch TV. I have saved the channel names in an array, but when I try to append an array item to an HTML element, it shows 'undefined'. The array is a global variable.

My code is [in this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r6xk3oqL/).

HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid">

<div class="row row-centered">

<div class="col-md-4"></div>  
<!-- This is a div containing divs for each channel --> 
<div class="col-md-4 col-centered" id="displayHere">


</div>
<!-- The container div end here -->
<div class="col-md-4"></div>  

</div>  

</div>
```

My Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
streamsArr=  ["ESl_SC2","OgamingSC2","cretetion","freecodecamp","storbeck","habathcx","RobotCaleb","noobs2ninjas","brunofin","comster404"];

 for(var count=0;count<streamsArr.length;count++){
 $.getJSON("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/"+streamsArr[count]+"?callback=?",function(data){

  if(JSON.stringify(data.stream)=="null")
   {
       $("#displayHere").append("<div style=\"padding:1%;\"><span style=\"font-size:1.3em;\"> "+streamsArr[count]+"</span><span style=\"color:red;\">OFFLINE</span></div>");//shows 'undefined'
    }
  else if(data.hasOwnProperty("error"))
    {
      $("#displayHere").append("<div style=\"padding:1%;\"><span style=\"font-size:1.3em;\"> "+streamsArr[count]+"</span><span style=\"color:red;\">UNAVAILABLE</span></div>");//shows 'undefined'
    }
  else{
  $("#displayHere").append("<div style=\"padding:1%;\"><span style=\"font-size:1.3em;\"> "+JSON.stringify(data.stream.channel.display_name)+"</span>"+JSON.stringify(data.stream.game)+"</div>");
  }
}); 
 } 
});
```

Can someone tell me where the fault lies? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery / Ajax - $.ajax() Passing Parameters to Callback - Good Pattern to Use?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1194104/jquery-ajax-ajax-passing-parameters-to-callback-good-pattern-to-use)

Answer (score 1):

You have created a closure for the variable `count` since JavaScript has function scope, which is why the value of your count variable is always 10. With ES6, you can use `let` instead of `var` in the for loop so `count` will be block scoped.

Comment: Thanks! That worked in Firefox and Chrome, but not in Microsoft Edge and Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 1):

`$.getJSON` method is asynchronous so `For` loop may complete before current request returns a result. So value of the variable `count` becomes 10.

Here is a fiddle that works
https://jsfiddle.net/bkw5dLac/1/

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
streamsArr=  ["ESl_SC2","OgamingSC2","cretetion","freecodecamp","storbeck","habathcx","RobotCaleb","noobs2ninjas","brunofin","comster404"];

 for(var count=0;count<streamsArr.length;count++){ 
 getJSON(streamsArr[count]);
 } 
});

function getJSON(arr){
$.getJSON("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/"+arr+"?callback=?",function(data){
  if(JSON.stringify(data.stream)=="null")
   {
       $("#displayHere").append("<div style=\"padding:1%;\"><span style=\"font-size:1.3em;\"> "+arr+"</span><span style=\"color:red;\">OFFLINE</span></div>");//shows 'undefined'
    }
  else if(data.hasOwnProperty("error"))
    {
      $("#displayHere").append("<div style=\"padding:1%;\"><span style=\"font-size:1.3em;\"> "+arr+"</span><span style=\"color:red;\">UNAVAILABLE</span></div>");//shows 'undefined'
    }
  else{
  $("#displayHere").append("<div style=\"padding:1%;\"><span style=\"font-size:1.3em;\"> "+JSON.stringify(data.stream.channel.display_name)+"</span>"+JSON.stringify(data.stream.game)+"</div>");
  }
});
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">

<div class="row row-centered">

<div class="col-md-4"></div>  
<!-- This is a div containing divs for each channel --> 
<div class="col-md-4 col-centered" id="displayHere">


</div>
<!-- The container div end here -->
<div class="col-md-4"></div>  

</div>  

</div>
```

**Why OP's code not working as expected**

1) Variable `count` is a global variable to the **anonymous callback function**  in `$.getJSON`

2) $.getJSON is asynchronous. So anonymous callback function is triggered only after the success of get request.

3) When the anonymous callback executes, value of `count` will be modified in for loop. In many cases, it becomes 10. Because for loop completes execution before the callback is triggered

**Why my fiddle is working**

1) I have passed the value of `streamArr` at `count` to a local variable `arr`.

2) Since, `arr` is local variable to the function `getJSON`, its value will not be modified in for loop. So anonymous callback function works as expected.

Comment: Thanks! That worked perfectly. However, can you shed more light on why your code works while mine didn't? The only difference between your and my code, is that I had directly nested the getJSON within the for loop, while you included a callback inside the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try cleaning up the `$.getJSON` function up a bit first:

```
var twitchAPI = "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/"+streamsArr[count]+"?callback=?"
```

and then encapsulate the success callback in a closure that has the index bound to it:

```
$.getJSON(twitchAPI, function(count) {
    return function(data) {
        if (JSON.stringify(data.stream) == "null") {
            $("#displayHere").append("<div style=\"padding:1%;\"><span style=\"font-size:1.3em;\"> " + streamsArr[count] + "</span><span style=\"color:red;\">OFFLINE</span></div>");
        } else if (data.hasOwnProperty("error")) {
            $("#displayHere").append("<div style=\"padding:1%;\"><span style=\"font-size:1.3em;\"> " + streamsArr[count] + "</span><span style=\"color:red;\">UNAVAILABLE</span></div>");
        } else {
            $("#displayHere").append("<div style=\"padding:1%;\"><span style=\"font-size:1.3em;\"> " + JSON.stringify(data.stream.channel.display_name) + "</span>" + JSON.stringify(data.stream.game) + "</div>");
        }
    }
}(count));
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Does this code work because you have passed the 'count' variable as a parameter, while I didn't? Also, what's confusing is that how does the getJSON function work at all when the JSON object 'data' is not passed as a parameter like $.getJSON(url,function(data){});