# jquery: function parameter is undefined in success callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, callback

I am trying to access graphList within success callback, but graphList is undefined. I referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1194104/jquery-ajax-ajax-passing-parameters-to-callback-good-pattern-to-use?answertab=votes#tab-top) StackOverflow post. However, I am not able to access elem. Any help would be appreciated.

```
getGraphData = function (graphList) {
 $.ajax({
 type: "GET",
 url: 'someURL',
 beforeSend: function(xhr){},
 success: function(result) {
   console.log(result);
   console.log(graphList);//undefined
 }
});
}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, I do have , in the actual code. will update

Comment: check your variable before  `$.ajax({`. Because it seems nothing wrong. it should work

Comment: graphList is undefined, because graphList is not getting into your function

Comment: @GopeshSharma: screenshot is not of the greatest quality, but you can still see its not undefined  in #132

Answer (score 0):

Added creating getGraphList function as below, I can access getGraphList inside success callback

```
var graphList;
var promise = graphInit(response);
promise.done(function(data){
  getGraphData(data.graphs)
}

graphInit = function(response,graphList){
  getGraphList = function(){return response.graphs;}
}

getGraphData = function (graphList) {
  $.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: 'someURL',
  beforeSend: function(xhr){},
    success: function(result) {
    console.log(result);
    console.log(graphList);//undefined
    graphList = getGraphList();//available
  }
});
}
```