# Launching a function from a "AddEventListener"?

Tags: javascript

I have a function which needs to be called when the Event is triggered, but for some reason I am getting syntax errors. It used to work fine when I put the function inside the event listener, but now I need to be able to call it instead.

```
rbProject.addEventListener('change', rbProjectClicked()) { // LINE WITH ERROR

})

function rbProjectClicked(){

    txtReference.placeholder = "Insert project reference";
    txtTitle.placeholder = "Insert project title";
    txtReference.value = ""
    txtTitle.value = "";
    txtReference.disabled = false;
    txtTitle.disabled = false;
    document.getElementById('divProjectManager').style.display = '';
    document.getElementById('divAccountManager').style.display = 'none';

    document.getElementById('divAccountFeedback').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('divClientFeedbackOver').style.display = '';
    document.getElementById('divClientFeedbackUnder').style.display = '';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are binding the result of `rbProjectClicked()` to the `change` event, rather than a function reference.

Do this instead:

```
rbProject.addEventListener('change', rbProjectClicked);
```

Notice, I removed the trailing `()` from `rbProjectClicked`. The `()` invokes the function call, but you only want to bind a reference to the function. `rbProjectClicked` is a reference to the function.

Comment: Also this: http://mislav.uniqpath.com/2010/05/semicolons/ semi-colon are kind of optional.

Comment: Fair enough. Part of the confusion that article addresses is from developers, like myself, who use multiple languages every day, many of which require semi-colons.

Comment: @Joey Show me what you tried because it absolutely works if you did it right.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
rbProject.addEventListener('change', rbProjectClicked()) { // LINE WITH ERROR

})
```

In javascript, there are two ways to declare a function, you can declare an anonymous function like this:

```
function (params ...) {...}
```

Or a named function:

```
function name(params ...) { ... }
```

Named declaration are "interpreted first" so the order in which you declare them doesn't matter. If you did wrote

```
rbProject.addEventListener('change', rbProjectClicked);
var rbProjectClicked = function () { ... }
```

It wouldn't work. The following snippet would work. It is usually a good idea to declare things before you actually use them, but it's a matter of taste I guess:

```
rbProject.addEventListener('change', rbProjectClicked);
function rbProjectClicked() { ... }
```

What you really want is this:

```
function rbProjectClicked(){
    txtReference.placeholder = "Insert project reference";
    txtTitle.placeholder = "Insert project title";
    txtReference.value = ""
    txtTitle.value = "";
    txtReference.disabled = false;
    txtTitle.disabled = false;
    document.getElementById('divProjectManager').style.display = '';
    document.getElementById('divAccountManager').style.display = 'none';

    document.getElementById('divAccountFeedback').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('divClientFeedbackOver').style.display = '';
    document.getElementById('divClientFeedbackUnder').style.display = '';
}


rbProject.addEventListener('change', rbProjectClicked);
```

But, we're not finished yet. As I can see, you appear to have mixed up an anonymous function with a named function.

What you wanted to type is this probably:

```
rbProject.addEventListener('change', function () {
   // code here
});
```

As you can see, I declared a function as a parameter to `addEventListener`. A reason to use anonymous function is purely syntactic. It is sometimes easier to read.

Comment: ***You don't have to declare the function first. [Take a look](http://jsfiddle.net/Up7v9/).***

Comment: You don't have to bind an anonymous function to an event listener either. A declared function works just fine. It's never faster. You are simply giving `addEventListener` a reference to a function.

Comment: I didn't say he had to, I say he can do that. and notice I wrote that it's purely syntactic.

Comment: *"As I can see, you appear to have mixed up an anonymous function with a named function. What you wanted to type is this probably.* By what evidence do you draw this conclusion?

Comment: You wrote that it's easier to read and slightly faster. In fact, it's not any easier to read, it's never slightly faster, and can actually be less optimal if you use the same function more than once.

Comment: His line with the error shows him making the common mistake of calling his function instead of passing its reference. It doesn't show any indication that he confused passing a named function with passing an anonymous function.

Comment: and you forgot to see the `{ });` ?

Comment: You're right. I did overlook that. It's still not clear that he wanted an anonymous function, but you might be right. There are still a lot of issues with your answer. Please clean those up.

Comment: I've addressed the issues with my answer, now address the issues with yours.

Comment: @crush anonymous could be faster as I doesn't have to do a name lookup. It will create a new function object on the fly which should be faster than searching the name inside closures but it really depends.

Comment: Do you have any [evidence to support that assertion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/80802/does-use-of-anonymous-functions-affect-performance)? A function reference is a function reference is a function reference. ([also here](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/193225/anonymous-function-performance-settimeout))

Comment: @crush I'll check what I can do.

Comment: I'm not a JavaScript developer. I'm used to PHP, .NET etc. I just wanted a function I could call to run the code. Just need to run the same code on the event as well as on load, so thought it would be more efficient making a function.

Comment: @crush my test were inconclusive in some sense.. the anonymous function was faster in a for loop up to around 15 cycles but the named function was way faster with more cycles. Adding more closures makes the named function loop slowlier but it's not enough to say it's a bad idea to use named function insead of anonymous. That said, if the function doesn't use variables in an outside closure the named function is much much faster.

Comment: Can you post your test for review?

Comment: @Joey a function is fine. if you want to reference it multiple times anonymous functions are not the way to go.

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix I'm not even sure the difference, I guess the same as having private / public functions?

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix You could assign the reference of an anonymous function to a variable. That is what `var myFunction = function () {}` is doing, after all. Assigning the reference of an anonymous function to the variable `myFunction`.

Comment: @crush check http://paste2.org/GIXsFXCC You can change the variable times to an other value to check how it affects both version. the variable `i` is used in both function as a closure variable. The only difference here is that doing array[0].somevar = "allo" isn't going to affect other indexes in the anonymous version. The named version is referenced on all indexes none of them will have their own properties in some sense.

Comment: @crush this gaves me the idea what would happen if we don't store the function anywhere.

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix On each iteration of the loop, a new instance of that anonymous function is created, while only a single instance of the named function is created. The named function should win hands down. Are you saying you observed the opposite? Try using jsperf.com or jsfiddle.com by the way.

Comment: @crush change times to 10 for example.

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix I see what you mean, for very small iterations, anonymous is quicker; However, consider this: the difference is +/- 30ms at 5 iterations (in favor of anonymous), which is negligble. The difference is +/- 500ms at 1000 iterations (in favor of named).

You should try one where you store a reference to an anonymous function in a variable.

Comment: Wait, I just realized your named function is returning an anonymous function...why?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46772/discussion-between-loic-faure-lacroix-and-crush)